# How to implement Java interface anonymously in scala?

Tags: java, scala

Suppose I have a Java inteface

```
public interface Bar {

  public void baz(String st)
  public void jaz()
}
```

I want to implement above interface anonymously in scala within a function body like:

```
def foo() = {
val bar : Bar = new Bar() {
// how to do that ?


 }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I had to, I'd write it as:

```
val bar = new Bar {
  def baz(st: String): Unit = {
    // method impl
  }

  def jaz(): Unit = {
    // method impl
  }
}
```

Though my preference is to avoid side-effecting methods as much as possible, they don't play very nicely with functional programming

Answer (score 6):

```
val bar = new Bar {
  def baz(st: String) {
    // method impl
  }

  def jaz() {
    // method impl
  }
}
```